# Can you associate a member to another member?

Tags: members

For instance:

1. Parent is a member
2. Service provider is a member
3. Parents have multiple service providers.

So hopefully, I'm hoping to do a query that looks similar to:

```
get all service providers from that parent
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use one of the add-ons that connect member registration to channel entries and then use a relationship field to connect a member to other members. (alternatively, you could use a fieldtype a la select member)

Several member add-ons that connect members to channel entries:

- Zoo Visitor http://ee-zoo.com/add-ons/visitor/
- Safecracker registration http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/safecracker-registration
- Profile:Edit http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/profileedit

Comment: Zoo Visitor is what I was looking for. Can service providers request to associate themselves to a parent without using the admin tool?

Comment: You could do that using the profile update tag in your templates. http://ee-zoo.com/docs/visitor/tags/update.html

Each associate would update their own profile which would have the relationship field associating them to the parent.